# C# formatting sql table date column output when writing to text file

Tags: c#, datetime, streamwriter

My issue is I am trying to generate text files to email through my program. The program searches the sql table for date firstname lastname and some other columns and of course its writing the date and time into the file. I only want to write the date instead of the date and time into the text files.

Logic being used:
1. query data from sql
2. insert data into dataset
3. create datatable from dataset
4. write datatable to txt file

This is how it's being written into the text file

1/20/2014 12:00:00 AM | 76770 | 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM | 0.0000 | 
1/28/2014 12:00:00 AM | 74000 | 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM | 0.0000 | 
1/20/2014 12:00:00 AM | 76770 | 2/19/2014 1:02:47 PM | 28.5600 |
1/28/2014 12:00:00 AM | 74000 | 2/24/2014 11:50:32 AM | 7.0000 |

using this code:

```
public void writeData(StreamWriter sw, DataTable data)
{
    int i;
    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        object[] array = row.ItemArray;
        for (i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(array[i] + "\t | ");
        }
        sw.WriteLine(array[i]);
    }
    sw.Write(Environment.NewLine + "*****END OF DATA****" + Environment.NewLine + "Retrieved: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = finalTable;
}
```

I want it to look like this in the txt file

1/20/2014 | 76770 | 1/1/1900 | 0.0000 | 
1/28/2014 | 74000 | 1/1/1900 | 0.0000 | 
1/20/2014 | 76770 | 2/19/2014 | 28.5600 |
1/28/2014 | 74000 | 2/24/2014 | 7.0000 |

is there a way to shorten the dates like that?

Comment: You need to identitfy correctly your columns of type DateTime and then use a ToString(m/d/yyyy) to format the output. Using the Console.Write on a generic object calls the ToString() conversion without any possibility to give an output format

Comment: What are the names of the 4 columns defined in the database table?

Comment: so i would have to write each column individually to the text file after identifying the type datetime?

Comment: Try  this : sw.Write(String.Join("|",
   row.Field<DateTime>(0).ToString("M/d/yyyy"),
   row.Field<int>(1).ToString(),
   row.Field<DateTime>(2).ToString("M/d/yyyy"),
   row.Field<Double>(3).ToString()));

Comment: The fact is that you want a specific format for the DateTime columns so, yes you need to apply the specific format only to the DateTime columns

Comment: servicedate cpt paymentdate and paymentamt which in turn are datetime, text, datetime, decimel (i think). The thing is, i can't format the columns within sql because it's used for a different program. I am just reading the tables and drawing data from them

Comment: @jdweng - I tried that code and am getting a specified cast is not valid

Comment: because the foreach (datarow ....) ends it. (i believe)

Comment: However, if the last column is a decimal change the advice of @jdweng to _row.Field<Decimal>("paymentamt ").ToString();_ (and use the column names also in the other parameters)

Comment: I wasn't sure if the database for last field was a decimal or double.  I guessed wrong.  The DataTimes could be strings in database which will give same error.  You need to find which field is giving the cast error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this - I've also added an additional case to format any `decimal` values to currency format.

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    for (i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        if ( row.Table.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(System.DateTime))
            sw.Write( ((DateTime)(row.ItemArray[i])).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "\t | ");
        else if ( row.Table.Columns[i].DataType == typeof(System.Decimal))
            sw.Write( ((decimal)(row.ItemArray[i])).ToString("C") + "\t | ");
        else
            sw.Write(row.ItemArray[i] + "\t | ");
    }
    sw.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. You are a genius. I would have never thought of that. Thank you.

Comment: I just happened to be working on DataTable manipulation at the moment so this question was well-timed :)

Comment: any chance you know how to format the paymentAmt as well? in the Table the format is "money" so I i'm wondering why i'm getting the 4 decimal places.

Comment: I think the base type for money is `decimal` - you could try the same trick checking `DataType == typeof(System.Decimal)` and use `ToString("C")` where "C" stands for currency ... not tested though ...